# A Database Error Occurred In Node JS Error Number: 1048

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a problem, when I add `no` an error appears

```
code: 'ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR',
errno: 1048,
sqlMessage: "Column 'no' cannot be null",
sqlState: '23000',
index: 0,
sql: "insert into tiket (no, category, title, description, status) values (NULL, '4', 'title 1', 'tes on', 'open')"
```

in my database, I don't type `null` in the column

this is code in my model

```
serviceAddTiket:(data, callBack) => {
    conn.query(
    `INSERT into tiket(no, category, title, description, status) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`,
    [
        data.no,
        data.category,
        data.title,
        data.description,
        data.status
    ],
    (err, result, fields) => {
        if(err) {
            return callBack(err);
        } else {
            return callBack(null, result);
        }
    })
},
```

Comment: You are trying to insert NULL into the `no` column, like the error says...

Comment: I did use a **tiket** not a **ticket**

Comment: If this is a javascript question and not a SQL question like the tags imply you should include your javascript code in the question.

Comment: oke wait a moment

Comment: I think you should consider `console.log(data)` and see if there are any fields missing